# I have a project in that Front-End they have used the React JS and Back-end Lumen application but i cant found any related information

Tags: reactjs, laravel, lumen

I am a beginner I need to start from the Scratch. I have Joined in a start up company they have developed Android App for that they used lumen in back-end, but I dint have any idea about php framework, I have lot of questions 
1. what are the software needs to be install to work with(lumen and react js)
2.how to integrate react js with lumen
3.I have already installed the laravel, is that enough to work with lumen?

sorry if my questions are looks like insane I am beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lumen is the micro-framework by Laravel. You can make the API in it. for that you don't need to install laravel project. `composer create-project laravel/lumen blog` this is the command for install lumen using composer. and react js is for the front. how to use react js with lumen for -- you can use APIs in react js which you've created in lumen.